# Object rest spread is not working with babel-register

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Consider:

```
// runMain.js
'use strict';
require('babel-register');
require('./run.js');

// run.js
let o = {id: 1};
let o2 = {...o};
console.log(o === o2);
```

I have done this:
`npm install babel-preset-es2015`
`npm install babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`

And `vi ~/.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread","syntax-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

But still it is not worked when `node runMain.js`:

```
C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:548
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: C:/workspace/git/LEGO/activity-lego/units/2015weather/run.js: Unexpected token (18:10)
[0m  16 | [90m// run.js[39m
  17 | let o [1m=[22m [32m{[39mid[1m:[22m [35m1[39m[32m}[39m[1m;[22m
> 18 | let o2 [1m=[22m [32m{[39m[1m...[22mo[32m}[39m[1m;[22m
     |           ^
  19 | console[1m.[22mlog[94m[1m([22m[39mo [1m===[22m o2[94m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m[0m
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\locati
on.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\u
til.js:91:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseIdentifier (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\par
ser\expression.js:1009:10)
    at Parser.pp.parsePropertyName (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\p
arser\expression.js:831:135)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\exp
ression.js:747:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parse
r\expression.js:479:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib
\parser\expression.js:265:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\par
ser\expression.js:245:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser
\expression.js:176:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (C:\workspace\git\LEGO\activity-lego\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\l
```

Babel version 6.2.0 (babel-core 6.2.1) 
Node.js version 4.0.0 (64 bit) 
OS version: [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7)

Comment: `bashrc` or [babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)?

Comment: Your `.babelrc` should also be in the project root, but your command makes it look like you have it in your home folder.

Comment: @loganfsmyth To put `.babelrc` in project root directory solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

As this question is not answered yet, but high rated on Google Search and I just had the same issue solved in my **React application without babel-register**(!), I post my answer here, as maybe it is useful for other people who end up here:

**Solution 1**

It is based on https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170

First install:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

Second, edit file *.babelrc*:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

**Solution 2**

It is based on *[Using the ES7 Spread Operator with Webpack](http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/frontend/using-es7-spread-operator-with-webpack/)*.

First install:

```
npm install --save babel-preset-stage-2
```

Second, edit of file *.babelrc*:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

In the link provided, the presets are set in the *webpack.config.js* file, and I am not sure what is the recommended way to set this setting.

**Conclusion**

Both ways let me use the ... [spread object syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and the error "Unexpected token" is gone.

I am *not* yet sure which is the recommended way, but I prefer the second at the moment, as it is easier to handle.